# Отобразить часть html из предыдущего вью в следующем. Laravel, теория

Tags: laravel, blade

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть один вид, с нем отображаются данные по товару, цена, количество и.т.д. , есть кнопка далее - переход в следующий вид, в котором я хотел бы отобразить часть html из предыдщуего, эти данные не должны быть интерактивными, всего лишь текст. Не хочется снова делать выборки

Если я верно понимаю, нужно парсить предыдущий вид, сохранять в переменную и выводить ее в следующем виде?

Comment: Пример бы, ничего не понятно

Comment: cart.blade: 
- выводим товары, добавленные в корзину 
картинка, наименование, количество, цена и другое
кнопка "оформить заказ" -> переходим в
checkout.blade: 
здесь нужно показать наименование и цену выбранных в корзину товаров 

по сути это строки из предыдущего шаблона и с ними не предполагается никакого интерактива, т.е. менять там ничего уже нельзя 
хочу показать просто как html 
а не делать снова выборку